# Excel function to round up a number based on 0.15 instead of 0.5

Tags: excel, function, math, excel-formula, rounding

Here's the table of data:

```
+---+------+---+
|   |  A   | B |
+---+------+---+
| 1 | 5.16 | 6 |
| 2 | 5.15 | 6 |
| 3 | 5.14 | 5 |
+---+------+---+
```

Column B shows the desired results of rounding a number up or down to nearest whole number based on the threshold of .15, instead of the standard 0.5.

The following function is best I've come up with:

```
=IF(B1-INT(B1)>=0.15, CEILING(B1, 1), FLOOR(B2, 1))
```

Is there any other solution involving less nested functions or less length overall?

Comment: `=ROUND(B1+0.35,0)`

Comment: @TimWilliams You should add that as an answer. I would love to upvote a much simpler approach then what I came up with. No need for VBA with your method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is shorter:

```
=ROUND(B1+0.35,0)
```

Comment: ROUND(B1 - (0.5 - (1 - 0.15)), 0); Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you are okay with using VBA, you can create a UDF *(**U**ser **D**efined **F**unction)*. Keep in mind that this will require you to save as a **Macro-Enabled Workbook**.

```
Function customRound(ByVal dNum As Double) As Double

    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        If (dNum - Int(dNum)) >= 0.15 Then
            customRound = .Ceiling(dNum, 1)
        Else
            customRound = .Floor(dNum, 1)
        End If
    End With

End Function
```

*Protip: You can rename the UDF to whatever you would like as long as the name is not already reserved within Excel. In this example, we are simply naming it `customRound()`*

You would then be able to replace your above formula with:

```
=customRound(B1)
```

---

If you are unfamiliar with VBA, read on:

> ***How do I access the VBE?***
> You can gain access to VBE by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> while you are inside your workbook.
>
> ***Okay, So I have the VBE open. Now how do I apply this UDF?***
> In the left pane you will see your workbook object modules. This is called the **Project Explorer**. You will need to create a new module, which you can do by `right-clicking inside the Project Explorer > Insert > Module`:
>
> [image]
>
> Now you can paste the UDF to this new module and you are all set!

Comment: This doesn't give the right answer. This would give `6` for all of the sample inputs.

Comment: @Enigmativity Good Catch. Fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly longer:

```
=IF(RC[-1]-INT(RC[-1])>=0.15,CEILING.MATH(RC[-1]),FLOOR.MATH(RC[-1]))
```

Comment: I don't know why this deserves a down-vote. It works perfectly fine.

Comment: Not sure either. Your answer is better than anything I could do with a formula. The only thing that I could think of was the OP requesting a shorter formula - but I can see how this answer would be useful to someone _other than_ the OP and his requirements that may tread on this question a year from now. Deserves my vote.